# Accessing AWS Elastic Search with Spring Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, spring-data

I know that AWS Elastic Search doesn't support the transport-client (only access via http/80) so is there another way of leveraging AWS Elastic Search using Spring Data?

AWS now supports ES 2.x so getting more interesting to use.

Any help or progress on this topic?

rgds

Colin